# Cannot add element to Map - Unsupported Operation Exception

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am having trouble inserting element to this mutable Map and i cannot figure out why?
I can see it returns Map so it should not an issue to put element in.
Can you help me with that?

`myClient.authentications.put("basicAuthentication", httpBasicAuth)`

Authentications look like this:

```
public Map<String, Authentication> getAuthentications() {
        return authentications;
}
```

```
private Map<String, Authentication> authentications;
```

Is there something that i am missing here?

Edit 1:
Adding some more code for clearance

HttpBasicAuth is just a basic class that implements Authentication

```
public class HttpBasicAuth implements Authentication {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyToParams(List<Pair> queryParams, Map<String, String> headerParams) {
        if (username == null && password == null) {
            return;
        }
        headerParams.put("Authorization", Credentials.basic(
            username == null ? "" : username,
            password == null ? "" : password));
    }
```

```
 val httpBasicAuth = HttpBasicAuth()
                httpBasicAuth.username = "user"
                httpBasicAuth.password = "pass"
                myClient.authentications.put("basicAuthentication", httpBasicAuth)
```

Comment: Right now, your code does not show how you are initializing `authentications`. Where is your value coming from?

Comment: Okay, i added some more code. Can you check again please?

Comment: I still do not see where you are assigning a value to `authentications`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That comment saved me some time. I am using a external library and looks like they are asigning unmodifiable map..

Comment: @IvelinIliev is my solution working?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, by default this field has `null` value so you CAN NOT call any method on it. So when you call:

```
myClient.authentications.put("basicAuthentication", httpBasicAuth)
```

you are trying call method `put()` on `null`.

## To solve it, you can change your initialization from:

```
private Map<String, Authentication> authentications;
```

To (in Java):

```
private Map<String, String> authentications = new HashMap<>();
```

or in to (in Kotlin):

```
private val authentications: Map<String, Authentication> = mapOf();
```

After those changes this field will be initialized with `empty array` instead of `null`. Remember that this change it's very important when you have some logic based on it (e.g. you are checking `authentications == null`).

Comment: `Currently, by default this field has null value so you CAN NOT add any valut in to it. `

I'm not sure what you're getting at here. The issue here is an unmodifiable map, not anything to do with null values. Unmodifiable maps or collections are commonly used in authentication libraries.